# phpredis: ERR: unknown command

Tags: php, redis, dockerfile, phpredis

I installed phpredis via pecl to my docker container (running with PHP-7.4.1-apache-buster):

```
RUN pecl install -f redis-5.3.1 && docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

I am connected to the redis server, but for all the commands I get: **ERR: unknown command**

```
$redis->select(1);

$redis->getLastError();

$redis->set('test', 'test');

$redis->getLastError();

$redis->get('test');

$redis->getLastError();
```

**Where getLastError() returns:**

'ERR unknown command 'SELECT'�'

'ERR unknown command 'SET'�'

'ERR unknown command 'GET'�'

It looks like error message contains some wrongly encoded character, which might be the cause of the problem.

I already tried to install different versions: 5.3.1 and 5.2.0 but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Our redis was in sentinel mode:

```
$redis->info();
//"redis_mode": "sentinel",
```

That means that first I needed to connect with RedisSentinel, then get the master address and then connect to that master as follows:

```
// connect to sentinel
$sentinel = new RedisSentinel('ip', 'port', 10);

// get the master ip and port you want to use
$address = $sentinel->getMasterAddrByName('your-master-name');

$redis = new Redis();
// connect to that master
$redis->pconnect($address[0], $address[1], 10);

// select the db
$redis->select(1);

// ready
```